# Response Headers missing charset

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I create a table dynamically which sets a button to load a 'more info' type modal, for some reason every so oftern I hit this issue where the modal won't appear and my errormessage catch supplies blank info.

The confusing part is it dosn't happen on all of the rows in the table, even though they are all created exactly the same.

The only difference I can see is the Content Headers contentType is missing the charset. but can't see any obvious pattern to why this is happening.

[Working Example of Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Pdb.png)

[Broken Example of Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFkYz.png)

```js
function filterData() {
  //$('#InfoAlert').fadeOut('slow');
  var res = validateFilter();
  if (res === false) {
    return false;
  }
  var almObj = {
    DateTime: $('#datetimepicker1').find('input').val(),
    Shift: $('#shift').val(),
    Text7: $('#area').val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/filterList/",
    data: JSON.stringify(almObj),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      $('#AlarmSummary').fadeOut('fast');
      $('#Table').fadeOut('fast');
      var html = '';
      $.each(result, function(key, item) {
        //Color the rows depending on time
        var cellcolor = 'black'
        if (item.TimeDiff >= 30) {
          cellcolor = 'orange';
        }
        if (item.TimeDiff > 60) {
          cellcolor = 'red';
        }
        //TODO: Remove pointless variable...
        var CounterID = item.Counter;
        //Display TimeDiff as minutes and seconds.
        var date = new Date(null);
        date.setSeconds(item.TimeDiff);
        var utc = date.toUTCString();
        var time = utc.substr(utc.indexOf(':') - 2, 8);
        //build table
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td width="15%">' + item.DateTime + '</td>';
        html += '<td width="15"><strong>' + item.Text2 + '</strong></td>';
        html += '<td width="40%">' + item.Text6 + '</td>';
        html += '<td width="15%"><font color=' + cellcolor + '>' + time + '</font></td>';
        html += '<td width="15%"><a onclick="return filterID(' + CounterID + ')"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Comment</button></a></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
      });
      $('.tbody').html(html);
      $('#Table').fadeIn('fast');
    },
    error: function(errormessage) {
      alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="table-responsive" id="Table">
    <table class="table table table-hover table-condensed searchable">
      <thead>
        <tr data-cell-style="cellStyle">
          <th>
            Date Time
          </th>
          <th>
            Facility
          </th>
          <th>
            Concern
          </th>
          <th>
            Downtime
          </th>
          <th>
            Update
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

the filterID function

```
function filterID(ID) {
  $('#CommentWarning').hide();
  $('#PText3Warning').hide();
  $('#Text8Warning').hide();
  var Counter = ID;
  var DateTime = $('#datetimepicker1').find('input').val();
  var Shift = $('#shift').val();
  var Text7 = $('#area').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Home/filterID/",
    data: {
      "Counter": Counter,
      "DateTime": DateTime,
      "Shift": Shift,
      "Text7": Text7
    },
    success: function(result) {
      //Display TimeDiff as minutes and seconds.
      var date = new Date(null);
      date.setSeconds(result.TimeDiff);
      var utc = date.toUTCString();
      var time = utc.substr(utc.indexOf(':') - 2, 8);
      $('#Counter').val(result.Counter);
      $('#DateTime').val(result.DateTime);
      $('#Comment').val(result.Comment);
      $('#Text2').val(result.Text2);
      $('#Text6').val(result.Text6);
      $('#PText3').val(result.PText3);
      $('#Text8').val(result.Text8);
      $('#TimeDiff').val(time);

      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#btnUpdate').show();
    },
    error: function(errormessage) {
      alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Something wrong in your back end. Note the content length is zero

Comment: You are right, I've literally just stumbled across the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Database issue, result set is basically 0 also made apparent by content length 0.